# Custom Button in Custom RelativeLayout match_parent not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a custom RelativeLayout that resizes to a desired ratio. I have overridden the onMeasure method that looks like this

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    float height = getMeasuredHeight();
    float mWidth = height / 711.0f * 320.0f;
    setMeasuredDimension((int) mWidth, (int)height );

}
```

this does exactly as I want it to resizes the width of my view.

I have a button that I have extended so that I can resize its height based on its width. I have overwritten the onMeasure method of this custom class with the following code.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    float width = getMeasuredWidth();
    float mheight = (width / 320.0f) * 60.0f;  
    Log.i(TAG, "measures width is "+width + " measured height is "+mheight);
    setMeasuredDimension((int) width, (int) mheight);

}
```

I have an xml file as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.breadcreative.Presenter.Core.SlidingRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pdarkgrey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:minWidth="328dp">

    <com.breadcreative.Presenter.Core.SquareImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/sidebar_logo"
        android:maxWidth="300dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PresentationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="PRESENTATION"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" />

    <com.breadcreative.Presenter.Core.SlidingMenuButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Library"
        android:id="@+id/pLibButton"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_plib"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="hidePanel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PresentationView"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp" />

    <com.breadcreative.Presenter.Core.SlidingMenuButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="User"
        android:id="@+id/pUser"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_puser"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pLibButton"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp" />

    <com.breadcreative.Presenter.Core.SlidingMenuButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Shared"
        android:id="@+id/pShared"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_pshared"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pUser" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="DOCUMENTS"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pShared"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <com.breadcreative.Presenter.Core.SlidingMenuButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Library"
        android:id="@+id/dLibraryBtn"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_dlib"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="MESSAGES"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dLibraryBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <com.breadcreative.Presenter.Core.SlidingMenuButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Inbox"
        android:id="@+id/messages_btn"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_messages"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />
```

My problem is this, If I set the

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

the custom button is too small, but if I set it to

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

the buttons width is the same as the devices screen, not the custom RelativeLayout which is what I want. what have I missed?